# What is wrong with this C++ map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I would like to be able to call specific matrices by a text string.  I am trying to set up a map to do this, but I do not have it quite right.

I notice that if I refer to the matrix I am trying to manipulate by its map name, it seems to work (i.e., `signalIndex["T2"].signal[i][0]=10)`, however if I try to refer to the matrix that the map label is pointing to, it does not work.  Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct signalGrid{
    double signal[20][200];
    signalGrid();
};


void mapTest(std::map<string,signalGrid> &temp_map);
map<string,signalGrid> signalIndex;
signalGrid testGrid1,testGrid2;


int main(){
    int i;

    signalGrid tempGrid;
    mapTest(signalIndex);

    tempGrid=signalIndex["T1"];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        tempGrid.signal[i][0]=5;}

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<"TEST="<<tempGrid.signal[i][0]<<"\n";}
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<"TEST="<<testGrid1.signal[i][0]<<"\n";}
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<"TEST2="<<signalIndex["T1"].signal[i][0]<<"\n";}

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        signalIndex["T2"].signal[i][0]=10;}
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<"TEST3="<<testGrid2.signal[i][0]<<"\n";}
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<"TEST4="<<signalIndex["T2"].signal[i][0]<<"\n";}
    return 0;   
}


void mapTest(std::map<string,signalGrid> &temp_map){

    temp_map["T1"]=testGrid1; 
    temp_map["T2"]=testGrid2; 
    return; 
}

signalGrid::signalGrid(){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        for(j=0;j<200;j++){
            signal[i][j]=0;}}
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example, in code, that you expect to work but doesn't. It's also not clear why you've included all these test cases. Do only some of them work? Could you tell us which work or which have problems?

Comment: I want to be able to manipulate "testGrid1" by referencing it as "signalIndex["T1"].signal[x][y]" so none of the test cases really work.   I don't know what the code is doing when I say, "signalIndex["T2"].signal[i][0]=10;"  It seems like it stores the information somewhere, but not in testGrid2, as I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manipulate with a reference to map item

```
signalGrid &tempGrid = signalIndex["T1"];
```

otherwise you are just changing two separate copies and the changes in one won't affect the other.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new copy in the below statement.

```
tempGrid=signalIndex["T1"];
```

modifiying tempGrid won't update the corresponding matrix in the map